# Jquery .each(): find elements containing input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which has a `thead` section and a `tbody` section. I'm using jQuery each to find and count all `TH`s in a `table`. This works fine. But at the same time I want to check if the `TD`s of the `TH`s in the `tbody` is containing any input elements.

Here is what I have so far:

```
jQuery('#' + _target).each(function () {

        var $table = jQuery(this);
        var i = 0;
        jQuery('th', $table).each(function (column) {
            if (jQuery(this).find("input")) {
                dataTypes[i] = { "sSortDataType": "input" }
            }
            else {
                dataTypes[i] = { "sSortDataType": "html" }
            }

            i++;
        });
    });
```

I hope this is enough information for you to help me out?

Comment: Why are you looping through an ID selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataTypes = $('#' + _target + ' th').map(function(i, th) {
  var $table = $(th).closest('table');
  var pos = $table.index(th) + 1;
  return { "sSortDataType": $table.find('td:nth-child('+pos+')').is(':has(input)') ? 'input' : 'html' };
});
```

**Edit:** if you are running this on a single table (in which case the `each` call in the original example does not make much sense), it gets simpler:

```
dataTypes = $('#' + _target + ' th').map(function(pos, th) {
  return { "sSortDataType": $(th).closest('table').find('td:nth-child('+(pos+1)+')').is(':has(input)') ? 'input' : 'html' };
});
```

Comment: this only returns an array containing "html" strings?

Comment: I had the arguments of the map callback in the wrong order. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (jQuery(this).is(":has(input)")) {
```

You can simplify your code using [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
    dataTypes = jQuery('th', $table).map(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).is(":has(input)"))
            return { "sSortDataType": "input" };
        else
            return { "sSortDataType": "html" };
    }).get();
```

Comment: `.is()` returns a boolean value, so length is unnecessary.

Comment: Why `.is(":has(input)")` instead of just `.has('input')` ?

Comment: @patrick: `.has()` filters the jQuery object; it doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: I think he wants to find out if the column headed by the TH has any input elements, not whether the header itself contains an input element.   This would be important in knowing whether the sorting needs to account for HTML or can use the data directly.

Comment: I see now the `length` is removed. I suppose it would be more efficient to avoid the filtering.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I hadn't seen that part.  I would have edited in the correct selector, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the counts could you not just use something like the following?

```
var thMatches = $('#' + _target + ' th');
var thCount = thMatches.length;
var thCountWithInputs = thMatches.find('input').length;
```

I've not got my IDE in front of me so the above may not be correct however I think it's pretty close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Each will give you the index of the element in the list.  Assuming that all of your TH elements belong to a column and you have no THs elsewhere in the table, you can use this to find the nth-child TD (column) elements of each row and see if any of those contain an input.

```
jQuery('#' + _target).each(function () {
    var $table = jQuery(this);
    var i = 0;
    jQuery('th', $table).each(function (column) {
        if ($('tbody > tr').find('td:nth-child(' + (column+1) + ')')
                           .has('input')
                           .length) {
            dataTypes[i] = { "sSortDataType": "input" }
        }
        else {
            dataTypes[i] = { "sSortDataType": "html" }
        }

        i++;
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: nth-child is one-based, whereas each is zero-based, so I've added one to the column variable to account for this.

Comment: `.has()` does not return a boolean.

Comment: @SLaks - Correct - I neglected the length property.  I've fixed this.